# Youtube API DELETE Playlists JQuery AJAX Request Being Sent as OPTIONS Request

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

Here's the request I'm attempting:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Deleting_a_playlist

Here's the request that is failing:

```
$.ajax( {
    dataType : 'json-p', 
    type : 'DELETE', 
    url : 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/playlists/' + playlist_id   + '?access_token=' + hash_values_json.access_token + '&alt=json', 
    headers : {
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
       'contentType': "application/atom+xml", 
       'GData-Version': '2', 
       'X-GData-Key': 'key=' + dev_Key }, 
   success : function(response) {
             }, 
   error : function() {
       alert("Delete of playlist failed."); }
   }
);
```

Here is the feedback from Chrome-Tools indicating the request is being sent as an OPTIONS request and more information:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQzjy.png

In the javascript console, I'm receiving the following error:
OPTIONS https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/playlists/760354511254461C?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZS51Dqs8F8CwkWq23LgevXCD7tWSJLVCLEBxEW22a2zNSY8OCxr 405 (Method Not Allowed)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/playlists/760354511254461C?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZS51Dqs8F8CwkWq23LgevXCD7tWSJLVCLEBxEW22a2zNSY8OCxr. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it's not possible to do cross domain POST/DELETE requests with JQuery AJAX yet (GET requests are okay however). How I got around the problem is sending a request to my server to perform the Youtube DELETE request.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `dataType` with `'jsonp'` (`'json-p'` is undefined).

=== UPDATE ===

Maybe you have to add the `Authorization: AuthSub token="AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN"` to the `headers` parameter or you should test `http://...` instead of `https://...`?

Comment: Thanks! Replaced, now I'm getting a "OPTIONS https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/playlists/760354511254461C?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZS51Dqs8F8CwkWq23LgevXCD7tWSJLVCLEBxEW22a2zNSY8OCxr 405 (Method Not Allowed)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/playlists/760354511254461C?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZS51Dqs8F8CwkWq23LgevXCD7tWSJLVCLEBxEW22a2zNSY8OCxr. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."